# A function to print a html table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I need the `write()` function to print a html table using JavaScript,the column names should be First name,Last name and Email sequentially.I can't get the names to print in the table.Don't know what i m doing wrong.Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Address Book</title>


<script type="text/javascript">
function addressBookItem (fname, lname, email) {
    this.fname= fname;
    this.lname = lname; 
    this.email = email;
}

addressBookItem.prototype.write = function() {

    var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);

    cell1.innerHTML=this.fname;
    cell2.innerHTML=this.lname;
    cell3.innerHTML=this.email;

}

</script>
</head>
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var aB1 = new addressBookItem('Roger', 'Williams', 'rwilliams@gmail.com');
    var aB2 = new addressBookItem ('Rose', 'Schultz', 'rose_s@earthlink.net');
    aB1.write();
    aB2.write();
</script>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td>Email Address</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Being new to JavaScript is no excuse for not trying. Everybody starts at 0.

Comment: Hint: Use th,td,tr and table tag to draw table

Comment: Why was this question closed? It clearly shows the OP has tries something, it contains code, shows clear understanding of JavaScript and the table API!

Comment: @edisonthk: Why? the insertRow/Cell API is part of the official W3C DOM API.

Comment: @koshi: The code looks pretty good. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @Harry: In which way did OP not try?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: You might want to have a look at the version of the question prior to Edit 2. It had no visible proof of trying to write the values to a table.

Comment: @Harry: Then how about reopening it now?

Comment: The current code works. http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/5JXMy/

Comment: @BarbaraLaird: Yup seems like OP did try after the initial comments and probably posted the resolution as an edit to question rather than as an answer.

Comment: The names dont go in to the table.it only prints the column names,i tried opening in different browsers still gets the same result.